# Include/Require 'file.php' ou Include/Require('file.php')

Tags: php, sintaxe

Sei que o PHP permite a inclusão de arquivos dos dois modos, mas gostaria de saber qual o jeito correto de usar essas funções, ou se os dois modos estão corretos.

Comment: Só pra complementarm tem include, require, include_once, require_once. Todas se comportam como o @bfavaretto mencionou.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`include`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php) e `require` são *statements*, não funções. Por isso, os parênteses não são necessários. Quando você os inclui, toda a parte dos parênteses é considerada uma expressão, e essa expressão é que é combinada ao *statement*.

Digamos então que é uma idiossincrasia de sintaxe. O jeito mais limpo de usar é sem parênteses, mas usar parênteses não é exatamente "errado".

Answer (score 5):

Conforme o manual do PHP, os parênteses não são necessários em torno de seu argumento, mas tome cuidado ao comparar o valor de retorno. Como o exemplo citado:

```
// Não vai funcionar, verificando se existe
// include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), Ex: include('');
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// Funciona!
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

Comment: Boa observação.

Answer (score 3):

require e require_once produzem um E_COMPILE_ERROR quando o arquivo não é encontrado ou não pode ser acessado. E_COMPILE_ERROR para a execução do script.

include e include_once produzem um E_WARNING quando o arquivo não é encontrado ou não pode ser acessado. E_WARNING não para o script, dependendo das configurações, é ou não exibida uma mensagem de erro junto ao HTML.

Vamos supor que você tenha um script que gere um relatório em PDF e disponibilize o download. É crucial gerar o relatório, mas o envio por e-mail para o gerente é opcional.
Sendo assim você precisa gerar o PDF mas se não enviar por e-mail não precisa impedir o usuário de ver o PDF.

Vamos supor que existam 4 arquivos:

- relatorio.php
- configuracoes.php
- lib/pdf.php
- lib/smtp.php

**relatorio.php**: O arquivo acessado pelo usuário e que faz a filtragem e tratamento dos dados e exibe o relatório na tela e envia por e-mail.

**configuracoes.php**: Arquivo que contém as definições de variáveis como dimensões do PDF, autenticação do servidor SMTP, e-mail do gerente, diretivas de session e error_reporting, entre outras coisas.

**lib/pdf.php**: Biblioteca que gera um arquivo PDF.

**lib/smtp.php**: Biblioteca que envia e-mails usando SMTP.

Nesse caso, o arquivo relatorio.php precisa do arquivo configuracoes.php e do lib/pdf.php
e o lib/smtp.php é utilizado, mas para a nossa lógica de negócios não é crucial.

Então faríamos o arquivo **relatorio.php** da seguinte forma:

```
require_once "configuracoes.php";
require_once "lib/pdf.php";
include_once "lib/smtp.php";

/*
    Código para gerar o relatório...
*/

$pdf = new PDF($relatorio,$configuracoesPDF); // $relatorio foi criada acima. $configuracoesPDF está no arquivo configuracoes.php. Classe PDF está no arquivo lib/pdf.php
if(function_exists("EnviarEmailComAnexo")) //Método EnviarEmailComAnexo está no arquivo lib/smtp.php
{
  EnviarEmailComAnexo($emailDoGerente, "Relatório gerado", $mensagemPadrao, $pdf.GetStream());
}

echo $pdf.ToString(); // Método ToString no arquiov lib/pdf.php
```

Consegue visualizar a diferença agora ?

Comment: Acho que você entendeu errado a pergunta. Não é sobre include/require versus seus respectivos _once, e sim sobre o uso ou não dos parênteses.

Comment: Sim, parece que entendi errado mesmo, entendi que você queria saber a diferença de include e de require e não se era para usar com ou sem parênteses.

Comment: É. Mas não fui eu quem perguntou, eu sou um dos que responderam :)